Dynamically export a type in typescript
I'm currently working on an application and I was wondering if it's possible to dynamically export a type.
I have an API call that returns me a list of categories.
const callApi = async () => {
  const categories = await axios.get(uri)

  // Something like ["fruits", "clothes", "shoes", "groceries", ...]
}

// Want to export a type Category that's only strings from the returned categories.
export type Category = "fruits" | "clothes" | "shoes" | "groceries" | ...

Is this possible in TypeScript? If not, what other approach can I take?
Thanks in advance!

It's not possible (and doesn't make much sense either.) Typescript types don't exist at runtime so you couldn't do anything with that type.

This is almost certainly an XY problem; what you're asking for isn't possible in the same way it isn't possible to write a cookbook that "dynamically" only uses ingredients from the reader's pantry. What is the underlying use case? What do you hope to do with Category in your TypeScript code? Is that data static or does it ever change? How would your code need to deal with possible changes? Does the code need to know anything about specific values returned, and if so, why?  Please [edit] to clarify the use case.

Just define the filter array and extract values to the type:
const filter = ["fruits", "clothes", "shoes",  "groceries"] as const;
const callApi = async () => {
  const categories = await axios.get(uri) as string[];
  const filtered = categories.filter(c => filter.includes(c));
}

// Want to export a type Category that's only strings from the returned categories.
export type Category = typeof filter[number];

